# Auto generate REST api documentation via RAML from Spring MVC controllers

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, raml, springfox

I am new to RAML. I want to auto generate my REST api documentation via RAML from my Spring MVC controllers. I know SpringFox has annotation based support for Swagger to auto generate api docs for spring mvc; Do we have a similar framework to auto generate RAML based api docs from spring controllers?

Thanks,
Lina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think RAML does note have a framework like SpringFox that generates a swagger from a Spring Controller.

There is a framework that generates a HTTP from a RAML like a swagger-ui.

This the framework: https://github.com/cybertk/grunt-raml2html

Comment: Seems like you are right. A good graphical comparison is done here http://www.mikestowe.com/2014/12/api-spec-comparison-tool.php .... As you can see the framework and build support is weaker in RAML that the Swagger .

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative that was open sourced recently is https://github.com/ePages-de/restdocs-raml. It is an extension to Spring REST Docs and generates RAML out of tests for Spring MVC controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the github project springmvc-raml-plugin for maven
https://github.com/phoenixnap/springmvc-raml-plugin

The plugin supports Raml 0.8, haven't found anything for RAML 1.0

Comment: This plugin now supports RAML 1.0 and does not support 0.8 anymore.